# Save an image to Shared Storage. Problem if the image exists with the same name

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I want to save an image to [Shared Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media), for Android 10 or high, and tell a user file name.

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put( MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, file_name );
contentValues.put( MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
contentValues.put( MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, 
Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+"/"+context.getString( R.string.app_name ));

uri = cr.insert( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
out = cr.openOutputStream(uri);
// and write a bitmap by compress method
```

It is works fine. But if the image exists with the same name, for example "image.png" then system will create file name "image (1).png", "image (2).png" etc.
How to get real file name?
And one more. How to get image file size for information. I use now this, but not sure that is the right practice.

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri , "r");
info_out.size = afd.getLength();
afd.close();
```

Comment: Use `DocumentFile` for both the display name and the length.

Comment: First check if the file already exists. And if so use its uri if you wanna overwrite the file.

Comment: @blackapps I can't check, I have not an uri yet.

Comment: Checking: You should query the media store for that file name and relative path. If you get a uri the file exists. Else not.

Answer (score 0):

Use cursor to get file name and check if it exist or not.Check the below code:

```
           Cursor returnCursor =
    getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
    do{ 
   String path=cursor.getString(nameIndex);
   File file=new File(path);
if(file.exists())
 {
 //your logic here
  }

   }while(returnCursor.moveToFirst());
```

Comment: I have not Uri yet. Insert method return the uri.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for pointing out my mistake.I have tried this to get the name of file and it actually works.Could you give me brief insight on why this code wont work?

Comment: You get file names. But you cannot use the File class to see if a file name exists. And your query can deliver thousend of names. What are you gonna do with them? Nonsense code. If you get a file name then that file exists normally. You dont have to check nothing more then.